# R Variable Name Contains Semicolon

Tags: r, string, variables, dataformat, pmml

I have a data frame. Lots of the variables have names like this:

```
/messages/with/:userid/
/:id/
```

I read the data using:

```
read.csv(file="file-path", header=TRUE,
           sep=",", check.names = F)
```

so that the original names were kept (by using `check.names = F`). 
I used **rpart** to train a decision tree model from the data, and then try to save the tree model to **pmml** format by using:

```
saveXML(pmml(dt.model, model.name = "DecisionTree_Model",
         app.name = "model_lr.pmml",
         description = "Decision Tree Model",
         unknownValue=0), "dt_model.pmml")
```

However, this leads to the following error:

> Error in field$class[[field$name[i]]] : subscript out of bounds

I believe the reason is that, the variable names contain `:` so that column indexing were messed up.

I could have read the data with `check.names = T`, so that the variable names would look like:

```
X.messages.with..userid.   
X..id."
```

However, since I'll need the original variable names for the **pmml** file, I want to keep the variable names as what they were. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pmml` package is pretty shaky internally - it's not such a good idea to do XML manipulation in R after all. If you're interested in the export of R models to PMML data format, then you might give the [`r2pmml` package](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) a try. It's written in Java (hence doesn't suffer from R language quirks) and is much faster and more functional.

The trouble with the `r2pmml` package is that it doesn't support the `rpart::rpart` model type yet. So, your best option appears to be the following:

1. Rename `data.frame` columns. Save the list of variable name mappings into a text file.
2. Export the `rpart` model into a PMML file using the `pmml` package.
3. Open the PMML file using [JPMML-Model library](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-model) and restore original variable names (based on the above mappings file). JPMML-Model provides special API (Visitor class `org.jpmml.model.visitors.FieldRenamer`) for that.